# Looping a paste, then group in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to put together some VBA in excel. Not overly familiar, but have managed to collate the following;

```
Sub PasteBOMLines()

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Set up loop
Dim loopCount As Integer            'Number of cycles to complete
Dim loopCountNow As Integer         'Number of cycles completed so far
loopCount = Range("B4")             'Get number of cycles to complete from cell
loopCountNow = 0                    'Set current number of loops to 0
Range("B6:N24").Select
Selection.Copy

Do While loopCount > loopCountNow   'Start of loop, continue looping until the number of loops completed is equal to number of loops to complete

'Paste and Group the relevant cell
ActiveCell.Offset(19, 0).Range("A1:M19").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1:F16").Select
Selection.Rows.Group

'Resolves loop
loopCountNow = loopCountNow + 1     'integer loops completed by 1
Loop                                'returns code to the "do while" bit

'Change settings to default
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'm having issues getting the grouping bit to work. If I leave out this bit;

```
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1:F16").Select
Selection.Rows.Group
```

The copy/paste function works fine, but once added in, the first copy/paste will group, then I get this error;

"Paste method of Worksheet class failed"

Any ideas? Thank you